# How to trigger the SQL Server database restore query from client machine to the server machine

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, localdb

I have a backup `.bak` file on my server, which I am restoring it using the SQL script which contains

```
Declare @dbname varchar(20)
Set @dbname = 'abc'

Declare @dbpath varchar(100)
set @dbpath = 'db_Path\abc.bak' ;  

RESTORE DATABASE @dbname
FROM DISK = @dbpath
```

Now I want to automate the execution of this script for which I have created a batch file.

I need to restore the database on my server machine from my client machine.

Is there any way to do that ?

Or can I execute the batch file on my server machine from my client machine?

Basically I need to restore my database on the server machine from my client machine using a task scheduler, `.bak` will be available on the server machine.
SQL Server is not installed on the client machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script runs ok in the server, ie

```
sqlcmd -i "restoring_script.cmd"
```

you may create a server scheduled task

```
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /ST "00:00" /RL HIGHEST /TR "script_to_run" /S "server" /U "user" /P "p@ssword" /TN "task_name" /F
```

and execute it from the client

```
schtasks /run /S "server" /U "user" /P "p@ssword" /I /TN "task_name"
```

see

```
schtasks /create /?
schtasks /run /?
```

for further details

Also,you may install the sql command line tools in the client system. You need three packages

```
SqlCmdLnUtils.msi (x86 or x64)
sqlncli.msi (x86 or x64)
SQLSysClrTypes.msi (x86 or x64)
```

Download *command line tools* for [SQL version 2012 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)
 or [SQL version 2008R2 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=26728)

and run the query from the client against the server

see also [sqlcmd utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)